# Create curved arrow using `tkz-tab` package

Tags: tkz-tab

I would like to ask if I can create a curved arrow using the `tkz-tab` package. [Here](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-tab/doc/tkz-tab-screen.pdf) is the documentation of the package. There are some examples of creating arrows, but not curved ones.

The reason I need them is to show that a function is either convex or concave. If someone can provide another solution, I would be grateful to hear.

Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
% XeLaTeX

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \tkzTabInit{$x$ /.8 , $f''(x)$ /.8, $f'(x)$/.8 , $f(x)$/.8}{$-\infty$, $0$ , $+\infty$};
    \tkzTabLine{,+,z,-}
    \tkzTabLine{,+,t, +}
    \tkzTabLine{,\nearrow,z,\nearrow}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

Comment: What code have you got at the moment? I mean: obviously you can use TikZ for this. What's the issue?

Comment: @cfr Is it clear now? If I use the `tikz` package how am I supposed to embed it in the `tikzpicture` environment?

Comment: Thanks. Yes. That's much clearer. Doesn't this diagram have a name? If so, try searching. It looks really familiar. I'm sure there are a couple of questions about them - maybe something helpful. (But I don't remember the name to search.)

Comment: @cfr It is called `table of signs`. I tried googling that, but there were no results. Anyway...

Comment: Probably you have to use regular TikZ similar to what's done on page 69.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this kind of what you were looking for? I use the list of available points in the `tkz-tab`-manual and use `calc` library to calculate coordinates of new points.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzTabInit{$x$ /.8 , $f''(x)$ /.8, $f'(x)$/.8 , $f(x)$/.8}{$-\infty$, $0$ , $+\infty$};
    \tkzTabLine{,+,z,-}
    \tkzTabLine{,+,t, +}
    \tkzTabLine{,,z,}
    \draw[red,thick,->,shorten >= 2pt,shorten <= 4pt] ($.5*(N14) + .5*(M14) + (0,.5mm)$) to [bend right=25] ($.5*(N23) + .5*(M13)$);
    \draw[red,thick,->,shorten >= 7pt,shorten <= 7pt] ($.5*(N23) + .5*(M23) + (0,.5mm)$) to [bend right=25] ($.7*(N34) + .3*(M24) + (0,.7mm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to upload an image, not a pdf file.  Just click the picture icon and select the file to upload.