# To show roots with even multiplicity in table of signs

Tags: tkz-tab

I want to show in table roots with even multiplicity, for this I want to use a double line and zero sign (not dotted vertical line ). But there exist 3 command in \tkzTabLine{d,-,z,t}, these is d, t, z commands. 
These don't work for me. How can I set new command instead of d,t,z commands?

- z places a dotted line and a zero centered
- t places a dotted line centered
- d places a double centered bar

I want to define new command, for example

- x places a double line and a zero centered
- y places a solid line centered

```js
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{tkz-tab,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{e}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{arrow style/.style = {blue,->,> = latex',
shorten > = 6pt,
shorten < = 6pt}}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=2]{$x$ /1, $f'(x)$ /1.5, $f''(x)$ /2,$f(x)$/2.5}{$- 
\infty$, $0$ ,$1$ , $2$ , $+\infty$}%
\tkzTabLine{ ,+,z,- ,d,-,z,+}%
\tkzTabLine{ ,-,t ,- ,d,+,t ,+}%
\tkzTabVar%
{ -/  ,  +/ ,-D+/  /  ,  -/  ,+/  /  }%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/new-users-how-to-do-good-questions-and-answers).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413453/table-of-signs-with-tikz?rq=1, your question is almost duplicate to it (you need to add only the last row with diagrams. So, show us what you try so far ...

Comment: I need a double solid line and a zero, and a solid line and a zero,

Comment: Please show what you tried so far to achieve the desired result in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471043/197451

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447188/197451

Comment: I think this closest to your requirement  --  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316418/197451

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a do-it-for-me question that does not show effort from the asker.

Comment: I just started using this package. I can do samples under tkz-tab posts.

Comment: Since the requirement has been changed from the original post please close and start a new question if you wish to

Comment: I can't delete it. How can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Final output after consulting

> http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-tab/doc/tkz-tab-screen.pdf

and

> https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347769/197451

The fourth arc is left as an exercise for the OP; similarly the double line with circle also as an exercise for the OP

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta,bending}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \tkzTabInit[color,
                colorT = yellow!20,
                colorC = red!20,
                colorL = green!20,
                colorV = lightgray!20,
                lgt=2, 
                espcl=2, 
                nocadre]
                {$x$      /1,
                $f''(x)$  /1,
                $f'(x)$   /1,
                $f(x)$    /1.2}
                {$-\infty$  ,
                $-1$,
                $0$,
                $1$,
                $+\infty$};


    \tkzTabLine{+,,+,,z,,-,,-}
    \tkzTabLine{+,,-,,z,,-,,+}
    \tkzTabLine{,,,,t,,,,}
    % \draw[red,thick,->,shorten >= 2pt,shorten <= 4pt] 
    % ($.5*(N14) + .5*(M14) + (0,.5mm)$) to [bend right=30] ($.5*(N23) + .5*(M13)$);
    % \draw[red,thick,->,shorten >= 7pt,shorten <= 7pt] 
    % ($.5*(N23) + .5*(M23) + (0,.5mm)$) to [bend right=25] ($.7*(N34) + .3*(M24) + (0,.7mm)$);
\begin{scope}[>->,line width=1pt,>=stealth]
\draw (3,-3) to [bend left=35] (2,-4);
\draw (4,-4.1) to [bend left=35] (5, -3.1);
\draw (7.7, -3.1)to [bend left=35] (8.8 , -4.1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If it meets your requirements please tick the check mark on the left of the answer and may also upvote on the upward pointing triangle at the left of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but that's not exactly what I want