# I am trying to make a simple table in latex

Tags: tables

I want something like this.[image: i know it's rough]

I have looked, but I can't find anything to help me.
This is my current code so far:

```
\begin{tabular}{r | l c c c c c r}
$x$ & -2 &  & 0 & & 2 & & 4 \\
\hline
$f(x)$ &  &  & 2 & & 0 & &  \\
\hline
$f'(x)$&  & $\nearrow$ & & $\searrow$ & & $\nearrow$ &
\end{tabular}
```

I've used `tabular` because it's the closest that I can get to what I want.

Comment: Hi! Welcome! Wrong image?  That is not a table....

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Simple table in LaTeX? Use `nicematrix` package :-)

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have so far? What do you want to change?

Comment: I can understand "my code doesn't do what I want", but the code you've posted is attempting to do things completely different than what you say you want.  I can't reconcile your picture with that of the posted answer.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta,bending}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\hspace{-3cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzTabInit[lgt=1,espcl=2,deltacl=1,nocadre]
        {   $x$      /1,
            $f(x)$    /1,
            $f'(x)$   /1
        }
        {   ,$-2$ , ,
            $0$, ,
            $2$, ,
            $4$
            };
        \tkzTabLine{,,,2,,0,,}
        \begin{scope}[>->,line width=1pt,>=stealth]
            \draw (4,-3.1) to [bend left=0] (5, -2.1);
            \draw (7, -2.1)to [bend left=0] (8 , -3.1);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: @GhidicVladislav -- I think you are looking for a variation table which can be made with the `tkz-tab` package -- please see if the answer meets the requirement -- since the documentation is in french feel free to revert with any queries -- my other answer with the same package -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521776/197451